# Android How to Remove white space / padding around vector asset in ImageView?

Tags: android, xml, imageview

I would like to remove the white space around my vector assets , I'm not sure how to do that. My files do not have any white space around them.
The issue ( I would like it to be like the red border I drew in paint):
[image]

This is one of my files:

[image]

Comment: If you are using ImageView or ImageButton widget then set the android:scaleType="center_crop" might solve your extra padding problem I think

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` property with your `ImageView` make sure you are using `android:src="@drawable/xyz"` to set your drawable not `android:background="@drawable/xyz"` in order for this to work.